# Populating a GridView issue

Tags: java, android, gridview, multidimensional-array

So I've been using a grid-view for several things in my application, and this issue is bugging me now as I am unable to solve the issue after about a week trying.

I am trying to populate a grid-view with my timetable which is currently stored in a multi-dimensional array, but the only index being populated is the first one. A copy of my BaseAdapter class is as follows:

```
    package com.ian.calendar.event;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.ian.calendar.database.DatabaseHandler;
import com.ian.campusmap.R;

public class ModuleEvents extends BaseAdapter {

    private String weekday;
    private Context context;
    private View view;
    private TextView[] textView;
    private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    private int eventNumber;
    private String[][] moduleA;

    public ModuleEvents(Context _context, String _weekday) {
        context = _context;
        weekday = _weekday;
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        dbHandler.populateDatabase();
        dbHandler.getTimeTable();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int i = 1;
        eventNumber = getEventsOnWeekday();
        moduleA = new String[eventNumber][6];
        textView = new TextView[eventNumber];

        do {
            if(weekday.equals(dbHandler.getTimeTableWeekday(i))) {
                for(int j = 0; j < eventNumber; j++) {
                    moduleA[j][0] = dbHandler.listArray(i, 0);
                    moduleA[j][1] = dbHandler.listArray(i, 1);
                    moduleA[j][2] = dbHandler.listArray(i, 3);
                    moduleA[j][3] = dbHandler.listArray(i, 5);
                    moduleA[j][4] = dbHandler.listArray(i, 6);
                    moduleA[j][5] = dbHandler.listArray(i, 2);
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        } while(i < dbHandler.count);

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_2, null);
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < moduleA.length; k++) {
            textView[k] = new TextView(context);
            textView[k] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtModuleID);
            textView[k].setText(moduleA[k][position]);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getEventsOnWeekday() {
        int events = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if(weekday.equals(dbHandler.getTimeTableWeekday(i))) {
                events++;
            }
        }
        return events;
    }
}
```

If you need any further class source-code feel free to ask.

Edit: Forgot to add that there may be some redundant code in this that I am still yet to remove. Sorry!

Edit2: Got rid of the do/while loop as mentioned by phtrivier

Edit3: I suppose no one knows..

Answer (score 0):

This part looks suspicious :

```
        do {
            return textView[k];
        } while(l < moduleA.length);
```

If means your "getView" function will always return the first TextView, and that's all ...

Comment: phtrivier: Sorry, part of my redundant code. If we was to remove that, and just do 'return view;' it would then only return the last index of the array.